# Configure font with variants

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, truetype

Is it possible to configure a donwloadable TTF font to behave the same way than a system font, i.e.:

- Font family is stored in several files:

  - `foo.ttf`
  - `foob.ttf`
  - `fooi.ttf`
- Font is assigned with the generic family name:

  ```
  p{
      font-family: Foo, serif;
  }
  ```
- Browser picks the appropriate variant automatically:

  ```
  p.warning{
      font-weight: bold;
  }
  p.note{
      font-style: italic;
  }
  ```

The documentation I've browsed suggests that you need to configure each variant as an entirely different font:

```
@font-face{ 
    font-family: FooRegular; 
    src: url(foo.ttf);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
} 
@font-face{ 
    font-family: FooBold; 
    src: url(foob.ttf);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
} 
@font-face{ 
    font-family: FooItalic; 
    src: url(fooi.ttf);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}
p{
    font-family: FooRegular, serif;
}
p.warning{
    font-family: FooBold, serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
p.note{
    font-family: FooItalic, serif;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Is it the way it is, or I'm just browsing deprecated/incomplete docs?

Comment: Have you tried giving each font-family the same name?

Comment: @duvigneau That's it! Thank you! *(Some web sites I've browsed are seriously wrong...)* - Feel free to add a proper answer so information gets archived for future visitors.

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for adding the proper code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact many tutorials ignore is that you can simply use a single family name and assign it to all rules:

```
@font-face{ 
    font-family: Foo; /* Just one name */
    src: url(foo.ttf);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
} 
@font-face{ 
    font-family: Foo; /* Just one name */ 
    src: url(foob.ttf);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
} 
@font-face{ 
    font-family: Foo; /* Just one name */
    src: url(fooi.ttf);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

... thus all the CSS you need is:

```
p{
    font-family: Foo, serif;
              /* ^^^ */
}
p.warning{
    font-weight: bold;
}
p.note{
    font-style: italic;
}
```

*Credit for the info goes to @duvigneau*

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
    @font-face{ 
    font-family: Foo; 
    src: url(foo.ttf);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
} 
@font-face{ 
    font-family: Foo; 
    src: url(foob.ttf);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
} 
@font-face{ 
    font-family: Foo; 
    src: url('fooi.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}
p{
    font-family: Foo;
}
p.warning{
    font-family: FooBold, serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
p.note{
    font-family: FooBold, serif;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

That way you add the styles to the same font family.